# Use JOLT to "stringify" JSON

Tags: java, jolt

I have a situation where my only method for modifying an API response's data is JOLT. For various reasons I need to 'stringify' the response using JOLT.

It's easy enough to use =concat to do this but it doesn't produce a valid JSON format, or something that's easily reversed.

**Example Input**

```
{"random":69,"random float":41.842,"bool":false,"date":"1988-01-23","array":["Pearline","Marita","Sonni"],"array of objects":[{"index":0,"index start at 5":5}],"Ernesta":{"age":73}}
```

**JOLT**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "x.&"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=concat('',@(0))"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "x": ""
    }
    }
]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
"{random=69, random float=41.842, bool=false, date=1988-01-23, array=[Pearline, Marita, Sonni], array of objects=[{index=0, index start at 5=5}], Ernesta={age=73}}"
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
"{\"random\":69,\"random float\":41.842,\"bool\":false,\"date\":\"1988-01-23\",\"array\":[\"Pearline\",\"Marita\",\"Sonni\"],\"array of objects\":[{\"index\":0,\"index start at 5\":5}],\"Ernesta\":{\"age\":73}}"
```

I tried to check the JOLT java code to see if I could tweak concat's behaviour to not lose the quotation marks, but I could not find anything.

I thought about using concat to restore the double quotes and colon but I quickly gave up. If anyone has a better technique, please let me know. Ideally the JOLT is generalized and not input-specific.

Comment: Can u please add the expected output JSON for the input you posted in the question?

Comment: @ArunSai - Added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry! I could not help you to achieve this with jolt, but I have the below alternate approach.

> NIFI FLOW:

[image]

faced the same issue in the past and managed as shown in the image.

Steps:

1. First fetch the JSON and put it into a user-defined file attribute using the EvaluateJsonPath processor.
   egg: Here I put your whole JSON into a flow-file attribute named as InputJson.

[image]
2. Now as the flow file & it's attributes enters into the UpdateAttribute processor, use [escapeJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#escapejson) function to escape the Json which we have assigned to InputJson attribute before intentionally, and after escaping, assign it to a new attribute.
egg: Here as you see I have assigned the escaped json to a new attribute named outputjson.

[image]
3. Now see the expected output as below:
[image]

4. Now ingest the outputjson attribute which has escaped json into json like below:
   JoltSpec:

[
{
"operation": "default",
"spec": {
"*": {
"finalOutput": "${outputjson}"
}
}
}
]

Note: The above jolt spec I just used as a sample to show how we can ingest/access flow-file attribute into jolt.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a NIFI based set up, just java backend that calls the jolt library